# What conclusions can I draw from this graph?

Tags: experimental-chemistry

I've been doing an experiment where we would have copper chloride in an aqueous solution, and then mix aluminium foil in it which produces copper. We then modified that experiment to do the same thing, but investigate the yield of copper with the solution at 10°C, 24°C, 30°C and 50°C.

I expected it to be a linear trend, with copper increasing as you increase in temperature, but with our results, I got this trend:

[image: Yield Of Copper Over Varying Temperatures of Copper Chloride]

My research question is this: 'How does changing the temperature of an aqueous solution of copper chloride (at 50°C, 30°C, 24°C and 10°C) in a reaction with aluminium affect the reaction rate and hence result in a greater yield of copper in grams?'

In my conclusion, I need to provide an answer to my research question and link **scientific theory to my results**. I'm not quite sure how I'm supposed to do that with the results I've got.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I would guess that the yield is constant and about equal to 0.8 g at all temperatures, if the validity domains are taken into account.

Comment: Let's start by confronting the obvious: there's no trend to be found in your data. Your error bars are so large that it's impossible to draw any real conclusion from it. (Science *is* like that sometimes, perhaps even most of the time; and the lack of reproducibility in your results may well not be your fault. But it *would* be your fault if you tried to discover some trend where there wasn't any.)

Comment: Repeat experiment but use CuSO4! The chloride ion is very particular with respect to the protective coating of Al2O3 on the Al. Some of what you may be observing relates to this surface chloride chemistry which may not be precisely even your topic of interest (or make it a topic of interest to explain the deviation). Relatedly, add some HCl to the CuCl2/Al experiment.

Comment: What are the sources of error (how did you dry the copper, and how did you separate it from other solids)? What was the color of the solution, and how fast did it change? The yield of product does not sound like a good way to measure a rate. Do you have any time-dependent data? Could you edit the question to give some more context about your data, and how your were hoping to answer the research question based on the outcome of the experiment?

Comment: What is the theoretical yield of copper? What is the limiting reactant, the copper salt or the aluminum foil? Could you edit your question to add that information?

Comment: I agree with @orthocresol. Fitting a quadratic (3 parameters) seems too much, fitting a line (2 parameters) would probably give a horizontal line within margins of error. You could plot all the yields (not the averages), and use the old-school method of enclosing them in a rectangle where the diagonals are the lowest and highest reasonable slope. Taking the average (1 parameter) seems the best option, quoting the standard deviation for the entire data set.

Comment: As mentioned by Karsten, it would be nice to see more experimental details (from Material and Methods - this is why this is included in reports, so people can gauge whether things were done properly, not just to repeat the experiment). How did you compute uncertainties? Did you stir the solution during the experiments?

Comment: First, the liberation of copper metal with a presence of Al enables a secondary electrochemical galvanic corrosive of the Al (see https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Comparison-of-the-Galvano-Fenton-and-the-Galvano-Fenton-with-pre-immersion-in-terms-of_fig4_353697572). At low temperature possible more dissolved O2 with solvated electrons forming superoxide and very acidic .HO2 at pH <5.  But warmer solutions, less O2 and also  less .HO2 but further raising the temperature offsets with an increased Cu formation, see reference. This explains the curve!